# Red code errors not showing up?

Tags: eclipse, compiler-errors, myeclipse

I am having trouble trying to activate(?) red error codes in MyEclipse Pro 2014 (I have the same problem in Eclipse Luna). I just downloaded it today and whenever I make an error, even on purpose like a misspelled keyword, MyEclipse won't show red marks on the side like how IDEs usually do. Is there any way I can fix this? Also, content assist doesn't work for me neither. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have the Java editor configured in preferences, file associations, as the default editor for Java files. If you're using the text editor, then content assist won't be available although errors should show up after saving the file. However, if you have disabled or removed the Java builder (in the project's properties Builders page), then no marks will show up. Try a new project in a new workspace to check if the problem persists.